# How can I find all internal links that are pointing to post/page?

Tags: links

I have deleted a page and now I want to find all internal links that are pointing to this deleted page.

So I need to know which posts/pages have a link to the deleted page.

Is there a faster way to do this than just manually checking all your pages and posts?

Please advise me.

Answer (score 3):

I found it is easier to use a service like https://validator.w3.org/checklink to check any broken link than checking through wp_posts database. You enter your site url and it will check through all the pages on your site and provide a list of broken links. You can then go and edit the pages with broken link.

Answer (score 2):

I would search the database's `wp_posts` table to find the URL(s) you are looking for, using phpmyadmin.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that the main menu also linked to this page and thus the search results returned all pages and posts. :-(

Comment: I think GhostToast's method should be enough, here is a sample query:

`SELECT CONCAT("http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=", ID, "&action=edit") FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE '%http://yoursite.com/the-url-to-find%' AND post_status = 'publish';`

You just need to replace `yoursite.com` and `yoursite.com/the-url-to-find` with the real urls

Answer (score 0):

I developed a plugin to show all incoming internal links to a post.
You can check it out [here](https://parsifar.com/how-to-find-all-incoming-internal-links-to-a-post-on-wordpress/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/249289)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[Slim SEO Link Manager](https://wpslimseo.com/slim-seo-link-manager/) plugin can help you do that.

The plugin scans all your content to find all links for you, including internal links and external links. And it gives you full reports of which links point to a post, or from a post. Here is a screenshot of the plugin, where you can see internal outbound and internal inbound links.

[image]

Another good feature of the plugin is that when you update your post slug/URL, all internal links will be updated as well. So, it keeps your links always active and fresh.